# Is the French J sound used in common English words

Tags: pronunciation, phonology

I've come across this French name *Jacques* and the first letter of this name is not pronounced in standard way with English names which starts with the same letter.  As far as I know, in English the letter J in the names which start with J is pronounces like G in the English alphabet.

I would like to ask are there any English words which have the same sound with J in the name Jacques.

The pronunciation of Jacques
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ft8M34gqw9I

Comment: I know of proper nouns not from French (e.g. Beijing, Taj Mahal) but I can't think of any common words.  Perhaps someone else can?

Comment: I'm not sure how the initial consonant for Jacques is that different than the initial consonant for the English version of the name, "Jack". Granted, there's a bit more to it, but it's generally the same sound. You don't say "Gak".

Comment: @catija English <j> or <g> followed by <i> or <e> are normally pronounced as an affricate, /dʒ/, with the fricative /ʒ/ preceded by a stop; French <j> is pronounced as the fricative alone, without the stop.

Comment: The <z> in *azure* and the <s> in words like *treasure*, *pleasure*, *leisure*, *vision*, *fusion* are all pronounced /ʒ/.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes they have the sound 'the French J'.

Comment: @StoneyB - If you post an answer, you might refer to this page: http://www.pronuncian.com/Lessons/Default.aspx?Lesson=119 It has many examples of the sound in use, although none of them are spelled with a "j."  I Interpreted his question (after my ambiguous rewriting) to specifically refer to the "j" spelling, but since Murat seems to like your answer....

Comment: Zha Zha Gabor is an an example.

Comment: @StoneyBonhiatus Your remark (azure, treasure...) should be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @Adam At the risk of being pedantic, although Taj Mahal and Beijing are both commonly pronounced by English speakers using /ʒ/, in both cases it's a hypercorrection where the Persian and Mandarin words both have something that sounds much more like the mundane affricate /dʒ/ that <j> normally represents in English <judge>!

Comment: @tea-and-cake interesting.. I hadn't known that.

Comment: I think because <j> is /ʒ/ in French and (transcribed) Arabic, both frequently-encountered languages to English speakers, there's a widespread notion that /ʒ/ is the default "foreign" sound for it.  I'd guess that standard Persian romanisation, and pinyin, were both influenced by English, and so <j> for /dʒ/ seemed reasonable to the designers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The letter 'J' usually represents the sound /ʒ/ in French. In English this sound is most often represented by the letter 'S'. A large number of the words that have this sound in actually came to us from Old French. Many of them end in -*sure*. Here are some examples:

- leisure, treasure, pleasure. closure, exposure, seizure (yes, that last one is spelled with a 'Z'!)

There are also many nouns originally from Latin which came to us from old French which end in *sion*. These endings are pronounced /ʒn/. Here are some examples of these:

- abrasion, adhesion, version, , allusion, aversion, circumcision, cohesion, collision, collusion, conclusion, confusion, conversion, corrosion, decision, delusion, derision, erosion, evasion, exclusion,  explosion,  fusion, infusion ...

There are also two adjectives ending -*sual* which usually have the /ʒ/ sound; *casual* and *visual*.

Lastly there are many words from ancient Greek with the ending *-sia*, often pronounced /ʒə/. Here are some examples of some of these:

- ambrosia, amnesia, kinesthesia, euthanasia, synaesthesia

The /ʒ/ sound is actually the rarest consonant sound in English. It nearly always occurs in the middle of a word. There is only one common noun in English ( - so I was told at university) which begins with the sound /ʒ/. This is the word /ʒɒnrə/, "*genre*".

*Hope this is helpful!*

Comment: My copy of the CMU Pronouncing Dictionary contains 89 words starting with /ʒ/, of which 87 are foreign proper nouns. The other two are _genre_ and _gendarme_. Looks like you were told right!

Comment: In your adjective list, you used "usually", but didn't include it as a third example!

Comment: I can add a third native word (or at least, nativised, arguably more than genre or gendarme) that starts with /ʒ/: the very informal British English word "zhoozh" /ʒʊʒ/ meaning "embellish, prettify, tart up": https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zhoozh

Comment: @tea-and-cake Yes, nice word!

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Here's a list of *all* the English words containing /ʒ/ from a computer search, minus varying forms of the same word, words that vary only by a prefix or suffix, and a lot of proper nouns. Most of these are well-known, though there are a few that are rare.

> abrasion
>   adagio
>   adhesion
>   allusion
>   ambrosia
>   amnesia
>   anaesthesia
>   Anastasia
>   Andalusia
>   anesthesia
>   aphasia
>   arbitrage
>   Artesian
>   Asia
>   aspersion
>   aversion
>   azure
>   barrage
>   beige
>   Beijing
>   bourgeois
>   brazier
>   Brezhnev
>   camouflage
>   Cartesian
>   cashmere
>   casual
>   casualty
>   Caucasian
>   circumcision
>   closure
>   cohesion
>   collage
>   collision
>   collusion
>   composure
>   concierge
>   conclusion
>   confusion
>   contusion
>   conversion
>   corrosion
>   corsage
>   cortege
>   countermeasure
>   crozier
>   decision
>   déjà vu
>   delusion
>   derision
>   diffusion
>   Dijon
>   dispersion
>   diversion
>   division
>   dressage
>   dysplasia
>   enclosure
>   entourage
>   envision
>   equation
>   erosion
>   euthanasia
>   evasion
>   excision
>   exclusion
>   excursion
>   explosion
>   exposure
>   extrusion
>   fantasia
>   foreclosure
>   Frasier
>   fusion
>   garage
>   gendarme
>   genre
>   Hoosier
>   hosiery
>   illusion
>   implosion
>   incision
>   inclusion
>   incursion
>   incursions
>   Indonesia
>   infusion
>   intrusion
>   invasion
>   inversion
>   leisure
>   lesion
>   lingerie
>   luxury
>   Magnesia
>   maharaja
>   Malaysia
>   massage
>   measure
>   mirage
>   misprision
>   montage
>   occasion
>   occlusion
>   Parisian
>   Persia
>   persuasion
>   perversion
>   pleasure
>   Polynesia
>   precision
>   preclusion
>   prestige
>   profusion
>   protégé
>   provision
>   raj
>   recision
>   regime
>   rescission
>   reversion
>   revision
>   revisions
>   Rhodesia
>   Roget
>   rouge
>   sabotage
>   seclusion
>   seizure
>   Solzhenitsyn
>   suasion
>   subdivision
>   submersion
>   subversion
>   supervision
>   television
>   transfusion
>   treasure
>   Tunisia
>   unusual
>   usual
>   version
>   vision
>   visual
>   Zsa-Zsa

I used the [CMU Pronouncing Dictionary](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict), which contains North American English pronunciations. In British English, many of these words end with /-zjə/ rather than /-ʒə/, though it varies by region.

Comment: Are there any pairs we can make with a word's non-voiced counterpart? I mean, do any of these have non-voiced counterparts, like peace/peas? I just mean non-voice the  /ʒ/ part... Sha-Sha? R<AW>sh?

Comment: @δοῦλος I just looked them over, and…no. There are some with alternative pronunciations with /ʃ/, but /ʒ/–/ʃ/ never distinguishes two words. Well, I guess we can dispense with the theory that you need a [minimal pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_pair) to have a [phoneme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme).

Comment: Can we remove Andalusia from the list - could be confusing as the people who live there pronounce it Andaluthia & to the rest of the country it's pronounced as it's spelt, no gz softening of the 'sia' [see-er] ending;) [I can't do phonetics, you may have noticed] Some of the others - Cartesian, Caucasian, in fact all the countries, end in 'zee-er/zee-an' to my ear, & don't have the gz sound. [BrE]

Comment: In fact, I'd go so far as to say all the 'sia' endings are see-er or zee-er to me. [Except, interestingly, Asia - though that reverts as soon as you extend the word to e.g. Asiatic]

Comment: @Tetsujin Good point! I used a phonetic dictionary of North American English. I'll add the details to my answer. As for Andalusia, my apologies to the Andalusians, but place names don't always get to retain their local pronunciations in foreign languages. Just think of Quebec, Moscow, The Hague, etc. In Italian, London is _Londra,_ Paris is _Parigi,_ etc. :)

Comment: @BenKovitz I'd say that the /zj/ often goes to /ʒ/ for British English speakers. /zj/ often goes to /ʒ/ anyhow just as part of a process of *coalescent assimilation*, so it can even occur across word boundaries for some speakers! (You could put that in your post, if you'd like. I was avoiding talking about it!) :-)

Comment: @Araucaria Thanks. I just looked into it a little, and yeah, that may get too complicated. If the OP asks for more than just "common English words with /ʒ/", perhaps one of us can provide the details.

Comment: @BenKovitz of course - I've heard some interesting pronunciations of Leicester & Worcestershire in my time;)

Comment: @Tetsujin: your plain-z pronunciations are sometimes heard in America, but most Americans pronounce -sian as one syllable, just like -sion.  It sounds a bit affected (snooty?) to pronounce that as two syllables. But you've got a point about "Asiatic".

Comment: @BrianHitchcock - I agree, see-an or zee-an is 'posher' than 'zhan' but would be considered 'more correct' in BrE even if not always adhered to.

Comment: @Tetsujin BTW, even if your keyboard can't type IPA, you can copy and paste from web pages (including this one). I often do that rather try to figure out how to type the characters.

Comment: Thanks, @BenKovitz - though half the time I don't remember it's called IPA so I start off googling 'phonetics' & 10 pages later give up & tipe it leik it soundz ;-)

Comment: @pazzo leisure and ledger, though in the U.S. the pronunciation of leisure is often different

Comment: "adagio" and "Beijing" only have /ʒ/ for some speakers, and it's a hyperforeignism that's caused by the French pronunciation of "g" and "j."

Comment: Back to the first comment, allusion and Aleutian (Islands) are voiced and non-voiced, where the voicing differentiates the pronunciation.

Answer (score 2):

In some dialects of English, many words borrowed from French will keep aspects of their French pronunciation.  (The silent 't' in 'denouement'; the silent 'r' in 'foyer', the fricative second 'g' in 'garage', etc.)

I can't think of any French words with 'j' that have been borrowed into English, however.

There are English words that have the French 'j' sound, but without the letter 'j' itself.  The three that come to mind are *vision*, *pleasure*, and *treasure*.  In all three, the 's' is pronounced like French 'j'.

(My native dialect is northern Ontario English, but I haven't noticed these words being pronounced differently in other dialects.)

Comment: I finally thought of one:  _bijou_ - not super common, but it is in Collins: http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bijou AmHerit: https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=bijou and MW: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bijou

Comment: Huh!  I've seen *bijou* in French contexts. The only time I can recall seeing it in English is maaaaybe names of theaters?  And in those cases, I can't swear how it was pronounced.

Comment: It is a useful word to have in your quiver for those moments when _chic_ isn't pretentious enough.

Answer (score 1):

The noun garage can be pronounced with a French j in BrE.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/garage_1?q=garage

Comment: I thought only Americans pronounce like that..In which part of England people say it with a French J, can I ask

Comment: In BrE there seems to be no strict form. It's either directly from the French pronunciation, gara′zhe, or totally anglicised as 'ga′rridge'… which leads to a bit of fun with the word sometimes spelled porage [more usually spelled & pronounced porridge]  ;)